# Docker DIND jenkins kubernetes - mounted directories are empty

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes, docker-in-docker

Having a weird issue running dind on k8s when mounting volumes from host

so I have docker which runs another docker container using host socket a specify -v command to that children docker but the mounted directory contains only .go directory.

The very same command works just fine on local machine

There's no errors in the output.

```
+ docker run -v /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/app/test:/src busybox:latest /bin/sh -c 'find /src'
/src
/src/.go
/src/.go/bin
/src/.go/bin/linux_amd64
/src/.go/bin/linux_amd64/linux_amd64
/src/.go/cache
```

Thanks

Comment: is your docker daemon in privileged mode? https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities

Comment: Please let us know if the solution posted by Hakan Dilek helped you. Additionally does a user which is running this command have appropriate rights to this files/directory.